# How to ship a pre-populated SQLite database in ionic 2?

Tags: sqlite, ionic2

I am building an `ionic 2` app that stores a large data. I have already a pre-filled `SQLite` database. I have checked the `ionic 2` documentation, and there is no enough information regarding this. Can any one help me on how to use a pre-populated `SQLite` database in `ionic 2`?

Comment: Couldn't you populate the DB from static tables in js/ts on first initialization of the app?

Answer (score 1):

This job is now very easy using cordova-sqlite-ext (not cordova-sqlite-storage!)

all you need is to put your sqlite db in /www folder and import sqlite native in app.modules.ts:

```js
import { SQLite } from '@ionic-native/sqlite';

providers: [
    ...
    SQLite,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
    ]
```

and in your .ts page file:

```js
import { SQLite, SQLiteObject } from '@ionic-native/sqlite';

private options = { name: "data.db", location: 'default', createFromLocation: 1 };
    private queryNames = "SELECT * FROM testTable";
    public names: String[] = [];

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private sqlite: SQLite) {
        this.sqlite.create(this.options).then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
            db.executeSql(this.queryNames, {}).then((data) => {
                let rows = data.rows;
                for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++)
                    this.names.push(rows.item(i).name);

                console.log(this.names);

            })
        });
    }
```

check this git project for a [working demo](https://github.com/iursevla/ionic2-PreDB)